# Django cannot unpack non-iterable Profile object error

Tags: python, django

i am trying to create multiple appoinments for a user and anytime i do it i get this error.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\USER\Desktop\cvbn\djangovueto\vuewe\aview\core\models.py", line 47, in create_appointment
    appointment,created = cls.objects.get_or_create(patient=patient,hospital=hospital)
  File "C:\Users\USER\Desktop\cvbn\djangovueto\sert\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\manager.py", line 85, in manager_method
    return getattr(self.get_queryset(), name)(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\USER\Desktop\cvbn\djangovueto\sert\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py", line 573, in get_or_create
    return self.get(**kwargs), False
  File "C:\Users\USER\Desktop\cvbn\djangovueto\sert\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py", line 436, in get
    num if not limit or num < limit else 'more than %s' % (limit - 1),

During handling of the above exception (get() returned more than one Appointment -- it returned 2!), another exception occurred:
  File "C:\Users\USER\Desktop\cvbn\djangovueto\sert\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py", line 47, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "C:\Users\USER\Desktop\cvbn\djangovueto\sert\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 179, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\USER\Desktop\cvbn\djangovueto\vuewe\aview\dashboard\views.py", line 31, in bookapp
    Appointment.create_appointment(hospital,request.user.profile)
  File "C:\Users\USER\Desktop\cvbn\djangovueto\vuewe\aview\core\models.py", line 49, in create_appointment
    appointment = cls.objects.filter(patient).order_by('id')
  File "C:\Users\USER\Desktop\cvbn\djangovueto\sert\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\manager.py", line 85, in manager_method
    return getattr(self.get_queryset(), name)(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\USER\Desktop\cvbn\djangovueto\sert\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py", line 942, in filter
    return self._filter_or_exclude(False, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\USER\Desktop\cvbn\djangovueto\sert\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py", line 962, in _filter_or_exclude
    clone._filter_or_exclude_inplace(negate, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\USER\Desktop\cvbn\djangovueto\sert\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py", line 969, in _filter_or_exclude_inplace
    self._query.add_q(Q(*args, **kwargs))
  File "C:\Users\USER\Desktop\cvbn\djangovueto\sert\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\sql\query.py", line 1358, in add_q
    clause, _ = self._add_q(q_object, self.used_aliases)
  File "C:\Users\USER\Desktop\cvbn\djangovueto\sert\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\sql\query.py", line 1380, in _add_q
    split_subq=split_subq, check_filterable=check_filterable,
  File "C:\Users\USER\Desktop\cvbn\djangovueto\sert\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\sql\query.py", line 1255, in build_filter
    arg, value = filter_expr

Exception Type: TypeError at /dashboard/connect/add/2/
Exception Value: cannot unpack non-iterable Profile object
```

Currently i can only create one appointment i want users to be able to create multiple apppointments.but i can create multiple appointments in my admin panel for a user with another user without any problem. The error seems to come from my get_or_create method. This is the models.py that has the method.

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.db.models.signals import post_save
from django.dispatch import receiver
from django.conf import settings


class Profile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, primary_key=True)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True)
    email = models.EmailField(max_length=150)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=255, null=True)
    margin = models.FloatField(default=20, null=True)
    amount = models.FloatField(default=20, null=True)
    country = models.CharField(max_length=255, null=True)
    phonenumber = models.CharField(max_length=20, null=True)
    appointment_with = models.ManyToManyField(User, related_name='appontment_with', blank=True)


    def __str__(self):
        return self.user.username
    
    def get_hospitals(self):
        return self.hospitals.all()





STATUS_CHOICES = (
    ('book', 'book'),
    ('approved', 'approved'),
)
class Appointment(models.Model):
    patient = models.ForeignKey(Profile, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='patientt', null=True)
    hospital = models.ForeignKey(Profile, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='hospital', null=True)
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    
    status = models.CharField(max_length=50, choices=STATUS_CHOICES, default='none')

    @classmethod
    def create_appointment(cls, hospital,patient):
        try:
            appointment,created = cls.objects.get_or_create(patient=patient,hospital=hospital)
        except cls.MultipleObjectsReturned:
            appointment = cls.objects.filter(patient).order_by('id')

        appointment.hospital.appointment_with.add(patient.user)
```

I am adding my urls.py and views

```
from django.urls import path, re_path
from .views import dashboard, profile, bookapp, acceptapp

urlpatterns = [
    path('', dashboard, name='dashboard'),
    path('profile', profile, name='profile'),
    re_path(r'^connect/(?P<operation>.+)/(?P<pk>\d+)/$',
        bookapp, name='bookapp'),
]
```

views.py

```
def bookapp(request, operation, pk):
     hospital = Profile.objects.get(pk=pk)
     
     if operation == 'add':
        Appointment.create_appointment(hospital,request.user.profile)
        
        return HttpResponse('You have booked an appointment')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem here is that you should either send a dictionary type or keyword arguments to your queryset filter in `appointment = cls.objects.filter(patient).order_by('id')` not a Profile object (if you are sure that patient is an instance of `Appointment` model). You should change it to something like `appointment = cls.objects.filter(patient=patient).order_by('id')` or `appointment = cls.objects.filter(patient_id=patient.id).order_by('id')`. As Django exception (mentioned in your question) I think changing the line `File"C:\Users\USER\Desktop\cvbn\djangovueto\vuewe\aview\core\models.py", line 49, in create_appointment` (line 49 in your models) will fix your problem. In the end I should say that type of appointment in your create_appointment are not the same (one of them is model object and the other is a queryset object) so do not forget to change them as well because if your views goes through exception, the line `appointment.hospital.appointment_with.add(patient.user)` will also raise an error.

Comment: I just got the error you said I will get. How do I make them the same?

Comment: don't know what object you need but you should change the line `appointment = cls.objects.filter(patient=patient).order_by('id')` to something like appointment = `cls.objects.filter(patient=patient).order_by('id').first()` or `appointment = cls.objects.filter(patient=patient).order_by('id').last()` based on your need.

Comment: That fixed it. But the multipe appointments still don't work

Comment: Or if you sure that some object of this model is unique (it means that only on object exists per this query) you can do something like:

try:
 appointment = cls.objects.get(patient=patient)
except Appointment.DoesNotExist:
 pass
else:
 appointment.hospital.appointment_with.add(patient.user)

because in `appointment.hospital.appointment_with.add(patient.user)` appointment type should be your model object not any other type.

Comment: Am I replacing the former try with this or adding it to it?

Comment: You can replace `appointment = cls.objects.filter(patient=patient).order_by('id')` with that exception block that I mentioned in my last comment, but only if you are sure that this queryset will return only one object.

Comment: it returns multiple

Answer (score 0):

`appointment,created = cls.objects.get_or_create(patient=patient,hospital=hospital)` the line returns 2 objects while the `get` wait for only 1 object. You should sure an `Appointment` instance has unique with `patient`, `hospital` (together). If you can't sure with that which means multiple instances can have the same `patient` and `hospital` then you can not use the `get` method.

Comment: Is there an alternative? I've looked up on bulkcreate it doesn't work with signals. Meaning it won't save from what I read.